# How to I pass an object obtained through reflection to a template?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

So I need to get a class using reflection, because it is a private class and it's the only way I can think of to create on object of that type. Then I need to pass that object off to template class. I cannot figure out how to create the template class though.

For Example:

```
Type privateClassType = (Assembly.LoadFile(x)).GetType("Namespace.privateClass");
var Object = Activator.CreateInstance(privateClassType);
```

Now use it in a template class like List

So, how would I instantiate the List since I find no syntax to replace T with privateClassType or any other way since the class is private and I have no access to it.

Any ideas on how I would declare the List to be correct?

Comment: Templates is a part of C++, generics are the syntax alike system in C#. They're actually two completely different things, except that their syntax looks a lot alike.

Comment: Thanks, you can tell I am not an expert C#, but I'm trying ;) thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, in C# space, we call them generics and they are VERY different animals from C++ templates.

Second, to close an open generic type (that is, a generic type with type parameters that haven't been specified), use `Type.MakeGenericType`:

```
Type openListType = typeof(List<>);
var closedListType = openListType.MakeGenericType(new[] { privateClassType });
object list = Activator.CreateInstance(closedListType);
// list is List<T> where typeof(T) == privateClassType
```

Third, it smells bad that you are creating instances of a `private` class. They are `private` for a reason.

Comment: I realize it smells bad, but Microsoft has some bugs in its source and symbol server implementation with regards to static libraries. And in order to get my symbols to delete through the normal retention policy I need access to one of their private classes (SymStoreTransaction) to pass it to WirteBuildInformation. Until Microsoft to fix the bug I really have no way to do it, unless I wrote my own retention policy and that smells worse.

Comment: Thanks For the help. Got it compiling at least ;) I'll have to test my stuff still, but at least I have the basics down.